# Why is my code not working properly? Is there something in STL-list which I am forgetting?

Tags: c++, list, stl

**This is my code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <list>

using namespace std;

template <class T>

void display(list<T> l){

    list<int>::iterator i;
    for (i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++)
    {
        cout << *i << " ";
    }
}

void enter(list<int> l){

    list<int>::iterator i;
    int index = 1;
    for (i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++, index++)
    {
        // cout << "check" << endl;
        cout << "Enter element at index " << index << endl;
        cin >> *i;

    }
    
    
}

int main(){

    list<int> l;
    display(l);
    cout << endl;
    l.push_front(1);
    l.push_front(2);
    l.push_front(3);
    l.push_front(4);
    l.push_front(5);

    list<int> l2(3);
    enter(l2);
    display(l2);
    cout << "EXE";
    return 0;
}
```

**The output of the following program is:**

```
Enter element at index 1

1

Enter element at index 2

2

Enter element at index 3

3

0 0 0 EXE
```

**Required Output:**

```
Enter element at index 1

1

Enter element at index 2

2

Enter element at index 3

3

1 2 3 EXE
```

Comment: Can you put the exact code that you're compiling? What is written in the question doesn't compile.

Comment: @SrijanSinha Please format your post properly next time so it's actually readable. While posting there is a preview so you can see how it looks. I did it for you this time.

Comment: @navyblue It does if you include the parts of the code that were obscured by the invalid formatting because they looked like HTML tags (e.g. `<int>`). I fixed the formatting, now it compiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you pass the list by value in `enter`. When you update the list with `cin >> *i`, you are updating a copy of `l2` instead of the `l2` declared in `main()`.

If you would like to update the list you will need to pass by reference instead.

```cpp
void enter(list<int>& l){

  list<int>::iterator i;
  int index = 1;
  for (i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++, index++)
  {
      // cout << "check" << endl;
      cout << "Enter element at index " << index << endl;
      cin >> *i;

  }
}
```